# RethinkDB - Reduce results of list field

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have a dataset with a field that contains a list of strings for each document. I'm looking for a query that will give me the list of unique strings in that field

I thought reduce might be what I'm looking for:

```
r.db('test').table('entity')('listField').reduce(function (left, right) {
  var i;
  var l;
  for (i = 0, l = right.length; i < l; i ++) {
    if (left.not().contains(right[i])) {
      left.append(right[i]);
    }
  }
  return left;
}).default([])
```

But this only returns the `listField` of the first item in the list: `["C", "F", "G"]`.  Any document in the table can have any number of an unknown list of values in `listField`. How do I get the list of all available values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that client side scripts cannot work in RethinkDB: these are just two very different scopes. RethinkDB only requires you to supply a ReQL expression that can be evaluated on the server side. By a ReQL expression I mean the stuff that can be found in the [JavaScript ReQL command reference](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/), and not client-side statements of any kind (statements, assignments, loops, branching, etc). `reduce`, similarly to all the rest of the terms, can accept a function that can build *a new ReQL expression*, and *not meant to evaluate anything related to the query*. In your case, the `reduce` function returns the `left` expression term (regardless your operations over the term -- they all create a new expression), and that's why you're getting your document `listField` value. As a result, expression builder functions are invoked before the query is actually executed.

Since you just want to find a unique value, you can rewrite the query and easily use RethinkDB built-ins like [`concatMap`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/concat_map/) and [`distinct`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/distinct/) (these operations are very basic not just in RethinkDB):

```js
//r.db('test').table('entity').delete();
//r.db('test').table('entity').insert([{
//  listField: ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
//}, {
//  listField: ['B', 'C', 'A', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z']
//}]);

r.db('test')
  .table('entity')
  .concatMap(r.row('listField'))
  .distinct();
```

And you'll obtain the result:

```
[
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "Z"
]
```

The query above can be rewritten with an expression build function as well:

```js
r.db('test')
  .table('entity')
  .concatMap(row => {
    // your local stuff here that is executed before the query is sent to the server and executed
    // note that this function must return a ReQL expression
    return row.getField('listField');
  })
  .distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew `distinct`, but not `concatMap`. Ended up adding `.hasFields('listField')` before `concatMap`, since not all documents have `listField` and that causes an error.